# Java code for sorting records along with subrecords in SAP PO

Tags: java, sap-pi

I'm trying to implement the below scenario in SAP PO to perform the below action

Below is the input format:

```
Code 1:    Position

HEADER1       P1    
HEADER1       P2    
HEADER3       P3
 ITEM1  
HEADER1       P4    
HEADER2       P5    
 ITEM2  
HEADER2       P6    
 ITEM3  
HEADER3       P7
```

We need to convert input structure into below format(sorting the Header based on order(HEADER1,HEADER2,HEADER3,...)):

```
Code 2:     Position

HEADER1        P1
HEADER1        P2
HEADER1        P3
HEADER2        P4
 ITEM2
HEADER2        P5
 ITEM3
HEADER3        P6
 ITEM1
HEADER3        P7
```

The ITEM records should be placed below the respective HEADER records, i have used graphical mapping and after transformation its getting placed as below: 
for eg: The ITEM1 under HEADER3 in position P3 in the Code 1 after sorting ITEM1 should be placed under HEADER3 in the position P6 in Code 2,
but ITEM1 is coming under HEADER1 in position P3 as shown in Code 3.

```
Code 3:        Position

HEADER1          P1
HEADER1          P2
HEADER1          P3
 ITEM1
HEADER2          P4
HEADER2          P5
 ITEM2
HEADER3          P6
 ITEM3
HEADER3          P7
 ITEM4
```

SORTING ORDER EXAMPLE

[image: SORTING ORDER EXAMPLE]

NOTE: HEADER is getting sorted as per the requirement but ITEM is not getting sorted based on the HEADER's position. 
 ITEM is transformed as it is as per the old position like in Code 1, in Code 3 also.

We are now trying to use java mapping for the above logic. PLEASE HELP ME IMPLEMENTING A JAVA CODE TO PERFORM ABOVE REQUIRED TRANSFORMATION like Code 2.

Comment: *"i have used graphical mapping"* Show what you've tried.

Comment: What should be the output if your input list starts with `HEADER2       P5`?

Comment: @ Arvind kumar avinash  if the input(Code 1) is header2 with item2 in P5 followed by header2 with item3 in P6,header3 in P7 after sorting there will be no change in position of header since its already received in order.